# The self-sizing custom cell in the XIB file not working. TableView also in XIB file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I must create the tableView in the xib file, and as we already know we can't create a Prototype cell for tableView inside xib . My cell also created in xib. I need to create an automatic height for it, but it's not working. Please help me to understand the problem.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question, and the image you included, doesn't tell us anything about where you're running into trouble. Please review [ask].

Comment: @DonMag thank you. you are a really talented developer.  Once you helped me.